Use of C# MemoryStream for encryption
I often see code that looks something like this (key and plain are byte arrays)
    byte[] cipher;
    using (Aes algo= Aes.Create())
    {
        algo.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        algo.Key = key;
        algo.KeySize = key.Length * 8;
        algo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = algo.CreateEncryptor(algo.Key, null);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // Sometimes another using StreamWriter/StreamReader if supplying 
                // string instead of byte[]
                csEncrypt.Write(plain);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            }

            cipher = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

I'm just wondering why the MemoryStream and CryptoStream are used.  Why not
    byte[] cipher;
    using (Aes algo= Aes.Create())
    {
        algo.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        algo.Key = Key;
        algo.KeySize = key.Length * 8;
        algo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = algo.CreateEncryptor(key, null);
        cipher = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length);
    }

Maybe TransformFinalBlock uses MemoryStream and CryptoStream internally so doing it that way is more efficient - I don't have access to the implementation so I can't really tell.  Alternatively, is CryptoStream using TransoformFinalBlock, in which case it is less efficient.
I've tried timing it to see if one runs more quickly than the other but stopwatch just gives me wildly differing results, even after 100000 runs.
Note: this is just a simple example - there is no need to go on about how bad ECB is.
The MS website C# example uses the MemoryStream/CryptoStream method so

Is it more efficient?
are they just giving an example of how to use CryptoStream?


How much data have you tested with? Are both options really equivalent? I would have expected repeated calls to .TransformBlock, followed by a single call to TransformFinalBlock, making these methods much more cumbersome to use directly.

TransformFinalBlock only gives you one block, what if your data is larger than that? For actual benchmarking you need BenchmarkDotNet, stopwatching is not good enough.

Its the other way round CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock will use encryptor.TransformFinalBlock to, as the name suggest, finish the crypto operation by doing specific stuff to only the final block. Often to apply padding as blocksizes of Cypto algorithms do not fit exactly to the length of the data. Your second code might work if data is shorter then the blocksize of the used algorithm. But that might  still be wrong for certain algos. I don't know them all.

In fairness, reading the source, TransformFinalBlock does seem to accept more than one block of input. I don't know if that was always the case... This post (by one of the C# team) does rather suggest that is the case, too

"Maybe TransformFinalBlock uses MemoryStream and CryptoStream internally so doing it that way is more efficient - I don't have access to the implementation so I can't really tell" -- it's the other way around: CryptoStream uses the methods on ICryptoTransform. You can see the source at https://source.dot.net, or on github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

@JonasH The data I'm testing with is in blocks of 16 bytes since that is how it the data comes in in my application.  Both methods give the same result.  I haven't had to use .TransformBlock.

TransformFinalBlock() can be compared with Java's doFinal(), both can be used for small amounts of data (for which the memory is sufficient). The stream classes are useful for larger amounts of data (for which the memory is not sufficient).

The old crypto API design (dating back to .NET Framework 1.x) was bit of complicated so you need to write a lot of code even if you just want to the simplest behviors. Microsoft also acknowledged other issues around CryptoStream.
Thus, back in .NET 6 many changes such as helper methods were introduced to simplify the developer experience. In your case you just need to call a version of EncryptEcb like this.

Sadly the internet is already full of legacy code, so search results/AI answers are poluted, and you might not always find the best sample to follow.

